# 16.04 GUI keeps asking for password

Tags: 16.04

I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. Afterwards the GUI would prompt me for my password and when I entered it would lock up.  Command line worked okay, however, so because I have a nvida machine I installed nvida-364.  Now when I enter my password the GUI blanks for a moment and then prompts me again, over and over.

I have a HP Pavilion desktop tower dual-boot with Windows Vista.